# Change default file manager in Fedora 23 - Cinnamon

Tags: fedora, nautilus, cinnamon

I just installed a fresh version of the Cinnamon spin of Fedora 23. As much as I love Nautilus/Nemo, I want to Set Thunar as my default file browser. I have tried commenting out the lines referring to nemo in the file `x-cinnamon-mimeapps.list` in `/usr/share/applications` and add the same line but pointing to `Thundar.desktop`. I also took a look at the mimeapps.list and gnome-mimeapps.list file lists as well.

I have Thunar installed and can manually launch it. However, neither Thunar nor Nemo show up in `alacarte` or `gnome-tweak-tool`. I haven't been able to locate the `default.list` system file to change that either.

**Any ideas?**

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately I have neither installed Cinnamon nor Thunar. But here is the solution for Gnome desktop. It should be very similar to Cinnamon.

First you should know the package name of the file manager that you want to set as new default. Open the `*.desktop` file laying inside your application folder e.g. `/usr/share/applications/Thunar.desktop`. There should be something like `X-DBUS-ServiceName=org.thunar`.

Here a few helpful commands that work for Gnome:

- Open the current default file manager for testing: `xdg-open $HOME`
- Print the current default file manager's name: `xdg-mime query default inode/directory` with an output like `org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop`
- Change the default file manager to Dolphin: `xdg-mime default org.kde.dolphin.desktop inode/directory application/x-gnome-saved-search`

Good luck!